# Remove rows from table based on user input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new here and I am looking for a bit of help please. I am learning jQuery/Javascript and have run into a problem which I just can't figure out.

I have a table and the rows are created based on the number a user selects from a dropdown. The user can add or remove rows by changing the number in the dropdown. This all works perfectly but I would like to add a tr directly after the `<tbody>`, this tr should not be removed by the user. All new rows, should appear after this initial row.

I have it working so the user can add new rows after this initial tr but if they attempt to update the number of rows in the table it all goes wrong! I just can't figure out how to fix this.

I am just looking for some guidance please. I have searched online and tried various things but because I don't quite understand why it's not working, I'm struggling to fix it.

```js
var row_f = 0;

function emptyRow2() {
  row_f++;
  this.obj = $("<tr class='test1'></tr>");
  this.obj.append('<td>' + row_f + '</td>');
  this.obj.append('<td><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input position-static G2" id="G2-' + row_f + '" /></td>');
  this.obj.append('<td><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input position-static M42" id="M42-' + row_f + '" /></td>');
  this.obj.append('<td><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input position-static M43" id="M43-' + row_f + '" /></td>');
}

function refresh2(new_countf) {
  //how many flats have been selected?
  console.log("New count Rooms= " + new_countf);
  if ((new_countf > 0) && (new_countf != 26)) {
    $("#noa1_header").show();
    $("tbody#noa1").show();
  } else {
    $("#noa1_header").hide();
    $("tbody#noa1").hide();
  }
  var old_countf =($('tbody#noa1 tr.test1').length);
  console.log("Old count Rooms= " + old_countf);
  //what is the difference? Do we need to add or remove?
  var rows_differencef = parseInt(new_countf) - old_countf;
  console.log("Rows diff Rooms= " + rows_differencef);
  // if we have rows to add
  if (rows_differencef > 0) {
    for (var f = 0; f < rows_differencef; f++)
      $('tbody#noa1 ').append((new emptyRow2()).obj);
  } else if (rows_differencef < 0) //if we need to remove rows...
  {
    var index_startf = old_countf + rows_differencef + 1;
    console.log("Index start= " + index_startf);
    $('.rooms-tbl tr.test1:gt(' + index_startf + ')').remove();
    row_f += rows_differencef;
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#id_noa1').change(function() {
    refresh2($(this).val());
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <table class="table rooms-tbl">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="w-75">Number of Rooms</td>
          <td class="w-25">
            <select class="form-control" name="noa1" id="id_noa1">
              <option value="0">- Select -</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
              <option value="11">11</option>
              <option value="12">12</option>
              <option value="13">13</option>
              <option value="14">14</option>
              <option value="15">15</option>
              <option value="16">16</option>
              <option value="17">17</option>
              <option value="18">18</option>
              <option value="19">19</option>
              <option value="20">20</option>
              <option value="21">21</option>
              <option value="22">22</option>
              <option value="23">23</option>
              <option value="24">24</option>
              <option value="25">25</option>
              <option value="26">25+</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>



<table class="table table-bordered text-center rooms-tbl">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <!--<tr class="text-center">
                        <th colspan="4">Rooms</th>
                    </tr>-->
    <tr id='noa1_header' style="display:none;">
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Option One</th>
      <th scope="col">Option Two</th>
      <th scope="col">Option Three</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="noa1">
    <tr><td>test</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: FYI you don't need to use `parseInt()` on the length, it's already an integer.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, appreciate that.

Comment: You don't have to write down the numbers 1-20 , Imagine if it was 100 , It would be dumb to write that long right , So use loops to do that job for you. It will make it much easier

Answer (score 1):

When calculating `index_startf` you need to subtract 1, not add 1. This is because `:gt` is zero-based, and it doesn't include the specified index (it's greater-than, not greater-than-or-equal).

You need to handle `index_startf == -1` specially, because jQuery doesn't understand `:gt(-1)` to mean that all the matches should be removed.

```js
var row_f = 0;

function emptyRow2() {
  row_f++;
  this.obj = $("<tr class='test1'></tr>");
  this.obj.append('<td>' + row_f + '</td>');
  this.obj.append('<td><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input position-static G2" id="G2-' + row_f + '" /></td>');
  this.obj.append('<td><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input position-static M42" id="M42-' + row_f + '" /></td>');
  this.obj.append('<td><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input position-static M43" id="M43-' + row_f + '" /></td>');
}

function refresh2(new_countf) {
  //how many flats have been selected?
  console.log("New count Rooms= " + new_countf);
  if ((new_countf > 0) && (new_countf != 26)) {
    $("#noa1_header").show();
    $("tbody#noa1").show();
  } else {
    $("#noa1_header").hide();
    $("tbody#noa1").hide();
  }
  var old_countf = ($('tbody#noa1 tr.test1').length);
  console.log("Old count Rooms= " + old_countf);
  //what is the difference? Do we need to add or remove?
  var rows_differencef = parseInt(new_countf) - old_countf;
  console.log("Rows diff Rooms= " + rows_differencef);
  // if we have rows to add
  if (rows_differencef > 0) {
    for (var f = 0; f < rows_differencef; f++)
      $('tbody#noa1 ').append((new emptyRow2()).obj);
  } else if (rows_differencef < 0) //if we need to remove rows...
  {
    var index_startf = old_countf + rows_differencef - 1;
    console.log("Index start= " + index_startf);
    if (index_startf == -1) {
      $('.rooms-tbl tr.test1').remove();
    } else {
      $('.rooms-tbl tr.test1:gt(' + index_startf + ')').remove();
    }
    row_f += rows_differencef;
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#id_noa1').change(function() {
    refresh2($(this).val());
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <table class="table rooms-tbl">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="w-75">Number of Rooms</td>
          <td class="w-25">
            <select class="form-control" name="noa1" id="id_noa1">
              <option value="0">- Select -</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
              <option value="11">11</option>
              <option value="12">12</option>
              <option value="13">13</option>
              <option value="14">14</option>
              <option value="15">15</option>
              <option value="16">16</option>
              <option value="17">17</option>
              <option value="18">18</option>
              <option value="19">19</option>
              <option value="20">20</option>
              <option value="21">21</option>
              <option value="22">22</option>
              <option value="23">23</option>
              <option value="24">24</option>
              <option value="25">25</option>
              <option value="26">25+</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>



<table class="table table-bordered text-center rooms-tbl">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <!--<tr class="text-center">
                        <th colspan="4">Rooms</th>
                    </tr>-->
    <tr id='noa1_header' style="display:none;">
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Option One</th>
      <th scope="col">Option Two</th>
      <th scope="col">Option Three</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="noa1">
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining some of the mistakes I made. I have created a fiddle based on your answer and made a slight change to the html. I'm not sure why I had originally missed it out but I have added the tr that should always appear directly after the tbody. The remove function is not able to calculate the number of rows correctly due to this tr I have added. I'm not sure how to get around this issue. Here is the link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wet1gyq6/

Comment: Why don't you use the `.test1` class when figuring the index and which rows to remove, so you ignore the extra row?

Comment: I guess it's not as simple as adding the class to the tr like this:
$('.rooms-tbl tr:gt(' + index_startf + ')').remove();

I am struggling to figure out the correct syntax

Comment: If that's your real question, edit the code in the question rather than linking to a fiddle in the comments.

Comment: Apologies, I thought linking to the fiddle was the way to do it.

Comment: You put all the changes from my answer into the question. Now my answer makes no sense.

Comment: I've changed the answer to just address your latest problem.